# Interact with content added with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple example

```
    <div id="test">add more text</div>
```

When you click on this text

```
    jQuery('#test').on('click', function (event) {
        $('body').append("<div id='newtest'>new test</div>");
    });
```

you get some more text appear.
After I have clicked on 'add more text' my page looks like this

```
<div id="test">add more text</div>
<div id="newtest">new test</div>
```

I am wondering what I need to do to interact with the newtest div?

If I put the below in.

```
jQuery('#newtest').on('click', function (event) {
    alert('not working?');
});
```

Nothing happens.
How do I interact with content that gets added after load? I thought .on helped me do this?

Comment: Did you put that after appending or before?

Comment: You need to use event delegation.

Comment: @Zyga No, live() was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: Live() is deprecated and has been replaced by .on()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you need to use `$(document).on()` instead of `$('#newtest').on()` is because `#newtest` is a new element that you have injected into the DOM.

You must now use `.on()` ) against an higher element *that was originally in the DOM*, in order to attach an event handler to the newly injected element.

Thus:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#newtest', function (event) {
    alert('This will work now');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply your click handler to the document.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#newtest', function (event) {
    alert('not working?');
});
```

Hope this helps!  :)

Answer (score 1):

put the event on your document instead of an element

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#newtest', function (event) {
    alert('not working?');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.on()` event to a parent element, such as the `body` and delegate it to the newtest `div`.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '#newtest', function (event) {
    alert('Working!');
});
```